# How to extract metadata from images in Sharepoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, metadata, image, sharepoint-library

Before this was done automatically, but Microsoft has removed it.

I would like to know some alternative to do this and to be able to add the metadata of the images to columns in sharepoint.

Is there any alternative with javascript, flow ... to do this?

Thanks,

Comment: What exactly do you mean by metadata of image? What information you want to extract from images?

Comment: The information I need to extract is the coordinates (latitude and longitude) that are found in the metadata of the image, in order to add it to sharepoint columns

Answer (score 0):

MS deprecated this earlier this year. https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/36665011-bring-back-sharepoint-online-image-metadata-extrac

We are forced to use a tool (Companion Explorer) to get GPS coordinates. This should be standard fucntionality.